# Array element manipulation dynamically

Tags: java

I have an array of strings with size 5.
These 5 Strings in the array is added dynamically. I have to display those arrays in my program. When a 6th element string /new element string comes, it should remove the 5th string in the array and the new element is added in the first position. Other 4 elements should be replaced to their next position. How it is possible without using loops ?

Comment: you should use ArrayList Inst-end of Array

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`

Comment: How can i implement it ? @AlphaQ

Comment: Go to this links http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Could it be any kind of data structure? I see a lot of users suggesting `ArrayList`, isn't an array, it's a list that behaves like an array. If any data structute could be used, you could use a `LinkedList`, allowing you to `removeLast` and `addFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example implementation using arraylist:

```
private void methodName() {
        //Initialize arraylist
        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();

        //Dynamically add the first 5 items
        stringArray.add("String1");
        stringArray.add("String2");
        stringArray.add("String3");
        stringArray.add("String4");
        stringArray.add("String5");

        //When a new item comes in (the 6th one), remove the last item and add the new item to the beginning
        stringArray.remove(stringArray.size()-1);
        stringArray.add(0, "String6");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without for-loops? To do that, you have to use ArrayList or a similar tool. Example:

```
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add("String");
    //repeat 4 more times
    array.clear();//removes all the objects
    or do
    array.remove([insert index]);//0-4 or array.size() -1 to get the last or see how much the max is
    array.add("new string");//you have now replaced the string you removed
```

You can avoid for-loops doing this, all though it is easier to use loops in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code and also the JAVA docs for further reference on `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//add values dynamically

list.remove(list.size() - 1); //remove last element

//let str be the new element
list.add(0, str);
```